# Efficiently merge file chunks

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hi I'm trying to merge a split file back together. I have this code working but it is painfully slow. Any ideas how I can speed this up? Each file chunk can contain up to 5mb chunks and there can be 100 or more chunks to put back together. I'm passing it an array of the chunk file paths "mergeFileNameArray" and also the "filename" for the new merged file.

Many thanks!

> ```
>     Dim STo As System.IO.Stream = System.IO.File.Open _
>                 (filename, _
>                  System.IO.FileMode.Create, _
>                  System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
>     Dim BW As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(STo)
>
>     For Each F In mergeFileNameArray
>         Dim STi As System.IO.Stream = System.IO.File.Open _
>              (F, _
>               System.IO.FileMode.Open, _
>               System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
>         Dim BR As New System.IO.BinaryReader(STi)
>         Do Until (BR.BaseStream.Position = BR.BaseStream.Length)
>             BW.Write(BR.ReadByte)
>         Loop
>         BR.Close()
>     Next
>     BW.Close()
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying files one byte at a time is not as efficient as it can be. Instead, you can copy chunks of the files using a buffer and [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileStream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s; at it's most basic:

```
Option Infer On
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub ConcatenateFileParts(fileParts As String(), destFile As String)
        Using outStream As New FileStream(destFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            Dim bufferLength = 32768
            Dim buffer(bufferLength - 1) As Byte
            Dim bytesRead As Integer
            For Each inFile In fileParts
                Using inStream As New FileStream(inFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
                    bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
                    While bytesRead > 0
                        outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                        bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
                    End While
                End Using
            Next
        End Using

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        ' I put a couple of files in "C:\temp\subdir" for testing.
        Dim filesToMerge = Directory.GetFiles("C:\temp\subdir")
        Dim dest = "C:\temp\merged.txt"
        Try
            ConcatenateFileParts(filesToMerge, dest)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("File merge failed because " & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

The `Using` construct makes sure that the filestreams are closed and disposed of properly.

You could make it more sophisticated by reporting progress, for example incrementing a counter afer each file part is copied.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I'm getting access problems "A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" any ideas how i might overcome this?

Comment: @WilliamContestabile OK, comment out the lines "Try", "Catch...", "MsgBox(...", and "End Try" and hit F5 to debug the program. Which line does it complain about now? If it is a line to do with reading the files, then the user runnning the program does not have read access to the files to concatenate, if it is a line to do with writing the output file, then then similarly but for writing with that file.

Comment: @WilliamContestabile You're welcome :) Did it speed it up much? You can try changing `bufferLength` to values like 65536 or 16384 in case it helps more.

Comment: massive difference, much much faster! Yeah I have had a play with the buffer. Think I will have to build in some time reporting and logging to figure out the most efficient settings. The chunk size and final file size and amount of chunks varies from job to job. Its going to take some doing to get it finely tuned but this Ferrari code is much better than my Lada code!