# Way to download file with BIM360 Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

I am in front of a problem using some limitation of Microsoft Power Automate, I have a flow that need to copy one file at a moment and sometime I have file that are more than 100mb and Power Automate doesn't accept http request larger than 100mb.

I am using the classical get_version then get_object. Is there another way to download "large" files from B360 ?

Thanks !

[Issue from PowerAutomate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxDq8.png)

Answer (score 1):

[GET Object](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-GET/) provides a header **Range** that allows you to download file by chunk. One demo call is available with the help document:

```
curl -v 
"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/apptestbucket/objects/test.txt"
 -X GET
 -H "Authorization: Bearer ShiAeQ67rdNSfmyEmtGW8Lnrcqto"
 -H "Range: bytes=44-83"
```

My colleague Bryan produced a blog on download manifest by chunk. It follows the similar header. The blog demos how to use this header in code. 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/download-large-derivatives-chunks

Comment: @Liang I understand the part to request the file in part but I don't find something to regroup these part into one file.

Comment: Simon, this will be a general topic of merging file with chunks. e.g. this post talks about how to merge by PHP, :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205445/how-to-merge-chunks-of-file-result-of-html5-chunking-into-one-file-fast-and-ef       and another one is by .NET   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624656/efficiently-merge-file-chunks